# Yodlee, Bank of New Zealand, SiteRefreshMode: NORMAL_REFRESH_MODE

Tags: yodlee

During integration Yodlee with loan management system I faced strange behaviour of Bank of New Zealand web site. 
According to Yodlee details Bank of New Zealand has SiteRefreshMode: NORMAL_REFRESH_MODE and it means that there should not be additional forms for authentication, but during refresh process I was not able to  get siteRefreshInfo.status = REFRESH_COMPLETED.

There is my refresh log looks like:

```
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = REFRESH_TRIGGERED, retryCount = 0
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = REFRESH_TRIGGERED, retryCount = 1
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = PARTIAL_COMPLETE, retryCount = 2
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = PARTIAL_COMPLETE, retryCount = 3
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = PARTIAL_COMPLETE, retryCount = 4
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = PARTIAL_COMPLETE, retryCount = 5
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = PARTIAL_COMPLETE, retryCount = 6
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = PARTIAL_COMPLETE, retryCount = 7
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = , retryCount = 8
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = , retryCount = 9
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = , retryCount = 10
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = , retryCount = 11
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = , retryCount = 12
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = , retryCount = 13
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = , retryCount = 14
siteRefreshInfo.code = 0, siteRefreshInfo.status = , retryCount = 15
```

After that I tried to log in to BNZ website and get form which requested to enter NetGuard details to proceed with login. As I can understand this is some part of MFA. But as Yodlee proclaims BNZ should have NORMAL_REFRESH_MODE refresh mode. 
If it is possible I would like to ask yodlee team what is wrong with BNZ. Why it has NORMAL_REFRESH_MODE but on site I can see additional data request.

Thanks.

Comment: I managed to resolve issue myself. The main issue was that I expected that refresh was finished if siteRefreshInfo.code = 0 and siteRefreshInfo.status = REFRESH_COMPLETED. Actually we can consider refresh as finished if siteRefreshInfo.code = 0 and siteRefreshInfo.status is null.

Answer (score 0):

This should ideally not happen. You should get value in "siteRefreshInfo.status". can you please tell where are you testing this? Is it on developer.yodlee.com?
can you provide the siteAccountID?

In Ideal cases -

siteRefreshInfo.code = 0 and siteRefreshInfo.status = PARTIAL_COMPLETE  denotes that Yodlee has scrapped the account summary level information and trying to get transactions.

And siteRefreshInfo.code = 0 and siteRefreshInfo.status = REFRESH_COMPLETED together determines that Yodlee has fetched all the transactions and completed the refresh.

Comment: I tested it on developer.yodlee.com and siteAccountId = 10038431